# Factorization of 2x2 rational matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to show that any $2\times 2$ rational matrix $M$ with positive determinant can be factored as $M=SB$ where $S$ has integer matrices, $\det S = 1$, and $B$ is upper triangular. I haven't made much progress, and a hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** as requested.  Write
$$M=\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}\ .$$
Since $\det M$ is not zero, $a$ and $c$ are not both zero, so there exists a rational number $s$ such that $as$ and $cs$ are integers with no common factor; hence there are integers $x,y$ such that
$$(as)x-(cs)y=1\ .$$
Now think about the matrix product
$$\pmatrix{as&y\cr cs&x\cr}^{-1}\pmatrix{a&b\cr c&d\cr}\ .$$

Comment: The hint worked, thank you.